# Exclude d.ts file from being generated

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

I got a util file which should not be exported as `d.ts` file as it is for internal use only. The file looks like this

```
// util.ts

/** @internal */
export const fun = function (...) {
   ...
};

/** @internal */
export const arrowFun = (...) => {
   ...
}
```

The issue is that with `declaration: true` I still get the `util.d.ts` file even if it looks like this

```
// util.d.ts
export {};
```

The tsconfig.json is

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2021",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "stripInternal": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/index.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/util.ts"
  ]
}
```

Is there a way how not to generate the file at all?

Please do not answer with `.gitignore` or `.npmrc` stuff. I want to keep this clear and easy to read without having people to search around why the file is not exported

Answer (score 0):

Per the typescript docs [`exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude) only modifies the behaviour of [`include`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include) but does *not* explicitly exclude a listed file from being included.

> **Important**: exclude only changes which files are included as a result of the include setting. A file specified by exclude can still become part of your codebase due to an import statement in your code, a types inclusion, a /// <reference directive, or being specified in the files list.
>
> It is not a mechanism that prevents a file from being included in the codebase - it simply changes what the include setting finds.

Regardless of any compiler option, if any explicitly included file `import`s or uses a `/// <reference` to another file in your code all transitive files will be included in the final output.

Thus, it appears the only way to remove this would be some sort of manual `postbuild` script.

Comment: it is fine that it is imported (in the end the code is being used). As it is a library, and those "utils" are not useful as content I just wanted to make the user experience as clean as possible. Sadly, as you say, it seems impossible :(